# Why setq cuts my list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

As the title says, I'm trying to append items to a list called solution, below is the code:

```
(defun add-solution (n)
    (let ((solution)) 
        (do((current-node '() (next-state current-node n nil)))
            ((equal current-node '(0 0 0 0)) solution)
            (if (goal-test current-node n)
                (progn
                    (format t "Cur: ~S~%" current-node)
                    (setq solution (append solution (list current-node)))
                    (format t "Solution: ~S~%" solution)
                )
            )   
        )
    )
)
```

Each time the new current-node is a something like:`(1 7 8 14), (2 4 11 13),` but when the loop returns it `returns ((1) (2))..`
What I need is `(((1 7 8 14) (2 4 11 13))`. Not sure what happened there??

edit: 
I added the format functions just before and after the setq, and the output was like:

```
Cur: (1 7 8 14)
Solution: ((1 7 8 14))
Cur: (2 4 11 13)
Solution: ((1)(2 4 11 13))
```

and after the whole thing is done the returned value became `((1) (2))` again. I'm not really doing anything that modifies `solution`...

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong in your code (except style issues, such as indentation). So, the problem is probably in the `next-state` function - maybe it is destructively modifying its first argument (`current-node`) in a way that causes the already collected nodes become invalid?

Comment: Yep. Solved my problem.. Thanks a lot! This was driving me crazy :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your error is somewhere else.

**Style:**

I would write/format the code like this:

```
(defun add-solution (n)
  (do ((solution nil)
       (current-node '() (next-state current-node n nil)))
      ((equal current-node '(0 0 0 0)) solution)
    (when (goal-test current-node n)
      (setq solution (append solution (list current-node))))))
```

Note that this is **bad code**, since you are **APPENDING** an item to the end of a list in a loop. This is a potentially very costly operation. Lisp lists are optimized for adding to the front, not to the end.

Comment: Thanks for the styling advice.